# Interface C/C++ library into HTML5 by using any tag

Tags: html, google-chrome, internet-explorer, c++11, firefox

My intention is to make a UI having following features:

1. Should be able to run/ work on all the OS platform like Windows, Mac & Linux.
2. Should be able to work with almost all the web browser like IE, Chrome, Firefox, etc.
3. Should be able to link or interface C/C++ library.

If possible can embed any other tool to link these C & C++ lib.

Actually here, there is no server involved. There is only independent application which has to link C & C++ lib and run on all 3 OS and almost every possible web browser.

Is it possible any how ? Kindly suggest me the most appropriate way to cross this hurdle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using Qt and open your HTML5 pages using qml webView element ? Qt code you can port to almost all the possible platforms, and above it you can run your HTML code.

> *Should be able to run/ work on all the OS platform like Windows, Mac & Linux.*

Qt code can be ported to almost all the platforms.

> *Should be able to work with almost all the web browser like IE, Chrome, Firefox, etc.*

You can use it over the qml's webView element or QtWebkit on almost all platforms.

> *Should be able to link or interface C/C++ library.*

Using Qt's C++ code you will be able to link to other libraries/processes via interprocess communication, if required.

---

These links might give an insight :

> 1. [qml WebView element](http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.7-snapshot/qml-webview.html#javaScriptWindowObjects-prop)
> 2. [Using qt with HTML](http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/17980)
> 3. [Choosing your UI weapon - C++ vs. QML vs. HTML5](http://qt-project.org/videos/watch/choosing-your-ui-weapon-c-vs.-qml-vs.-html5)